# How to insert (and later extract) readable program into MS Word

Tags: ms-word, insert, programmatically-created

I wish to insert/extract a program (python, Java, doesn't matter; it's text) in an MS Word doc.  The rest of the MS Word doc can contain essentially anything but with respect to the embedded program there are two requirements:

1. You can see (literally) the program in plaintext, so it cannot be an unrenderable binary object that is "stashed" into the doc.
2. The program can programmatically (ha!) be extracted or inserted into the doc without scanning or otherwise sniffing, i.e. the program is (if you forgive the analogy) is in a div that unambiguously contains it.  Whatever APIs are brought to bear on the program must essentially be of the form `byte[] (or char[]) content = worddoc.getRegionFromDoc("markerOfSomeKind")`

Obvious goals are simplicity in insertion/extraction and (best case) raw treatment of characters, i.e. Word doesn't try to apply formatting of any kind.